# In C++, and within the following constraints, how do I declare an array of size x where the value of x changes on each iteration?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a small program which needs to do as I have stated in the title. It will run `case` iterations of the outer loop (see below). Upon each iteration, it uses `cin` to read into `sz` which represents the amount of integers that need to be stored in array.

My issue is that the template declaration statement for an array needs a constant as the second template (size) argument, as in:

```
array<type,constant size> arr;
```

To get the constant, I tried to create variable `s` and set it to the value of `sz` at the beginning of each outer loop. Because it is defined inside that loop, I assumed this would be pretty straight-forward.

However, when trying to declare the array as below:

```
array<int,s> arr;
```

I am getting the following pre-compile error at `s` in the above declaration:

```
Non type template argument is not a constant.
```

I already know that this is because `s` is being initialized to `sz`, which is not a constant.

Since the entire program is just a few lines, and since the issue has proven difficult for me to simplify, I will include the whole thing here to clarify what I am talking about:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  int cases, sz, a;

  cin >> cases;

  // runs once per case
  for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++){

    cin >> sz;
    const int s = sz;
    
    array<int, s> arr; // here is the declaration


    //needs to add value to arr, and do so sz times per case 
    for (int j = 0; j < sz; j++){
  
  

    }

  }

  return 0;
}
```

I know that the include and namespace statements are not ideal. I am creating this in a context where the speed of writing overtakes the need for robust and high-quality code.

I also know a few ways to achieve the desired outcome (e.g. use of a vector, re structuring, etc.) However, for the sake of my sanity, I need to make this setup work. I know that achieving it will be simple, so long as I can somehow set `s` to a constant representation of `sz`'s value at the point when the statement runs. In other words, I am trying to take a snapshot of `sz` and use it to set the value of the constant. I've now spent a few hours trying to make this happen, and I am pulling my hair out. It is straight-forward in most languages. What am I overlooking? Can this be done within the confines of the standard library and using the template-style declaration?

Btw, if any (or most) of the other lines are off or make no sense, it is because I've been changing / changing back for quite a while now. I am getting tunnel vision from staring at it.

Comment: It has to be a compile time constant. Use a `std::vector`.

Comment: Can someone also explain me. Difference in doing ```int arr[s] ;``` and the ```array<int,s> arr;```.  When to use what

Comment: @Abhi - Code that must work with a pre-C++11 compiler/library requires `int arr[s]` (where `s` is a compile time constant) since `std::array` was introduced in C++11. Since C++11, there are very few circumstances in which you would not prefer `std::array<int, s>`. In fact, about the only *real* circumstance (C++11 and later) I can think of off-hand is using a freestanding implementation that does not have the `<array>` header -that is a highly specialised use case (e.g. a bespoke compiler for an embedded system where programs run on "bare metal") that few programmers encounter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In C++, and within the following constraints, how do I declare an array of size x where the value of x changes on each iteration?

You cannot use `std::array` for this purpose. You must allocate the array dynamically, because the size of all other arrays must be **compile time** constant. The most convenient way to create a dynamic array in C++ is to use `std::vector`.

> I know that achieving it will be simple, so long as I can somehow set s to a constant representation of sz's value at the point when the statement runs.

There is simply no way to make runtime input a compile time constant. Those properties exclude one another.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I've wasted most of my Saturday evening learning this the hard way. I just had to be sure..